# added subdirectory to CMakeLists.txt isn't detected by main.cpp

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cmake, pybind11, cmakelists-options

I'm working on creating a python binding to a c++ code using Pybind11.
My project architecture is the following:

```
-- MyProject
   | -- lib
         | -- pybind11
              | -- CMakeLists.txt
              | -- include
         | -- myCPPCode
              | -- CMakeLists.txt
              | -- MyCodeDefinitions.h
              | -- MyCode.cpp
   | -- src
         | -- MyProject
              | -- MyModule.cpp
   | -- CMakeLists.txt
   | -- setup.py
```

what I want to do, is to include `#include <myCPPCode/MyCodeDefinitions.h>` into `MyModule.cpp`.

In order to do that, I added into the global `CMakeLists.txt` the following command: `add_subdirectory(lib/myCPPCode)`, But it's not working, as I don't know what to put in `lib/myCPPCode/CMakeLists.txt`, and I'm getting the following error:

```
path/MyProject/src/MyProject/MyModule.cpp:2:10: fatal error: myCPPCode/MyCodeDefinitions.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <myCPPCode/MyCodeDefinitions.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The content of `lib/myCPPCode/CMakeLists.txt` is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(myCPPCode)


add_library(myCPPCode MyCode.cpp)
```

How should I configure my `CMakeLists.txt` and `lib/myCPPCode/CMakeLists.txt`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should never `#include` `.cpp` files. It that a typo?

Comment: Hi @super No, is not a typo. What should I do instead if I want to use a function defined in another file?

Comment: You make a `.hpp` file with the declaration in in. Then put the definition in the `.cpp` file. The `.cpp` file is compiled, usually as it's own translation unit, and when some other code needs to use those functions it just includes the declaration from the `.hpp` and it all comes together during linking.

Comment: @super I see, thank you for your comment, I will do that

Comment: @super I updated the question with your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_subdirectory` just tells cmake to find a CMakeLists.txt in the directory given as argument.

You need to change your `add_subdirectory(lib/myCPPCode)` into `include_directories(lib/myCPPCode)` and it should work better.

Comment: Hi @sylvain I tried your solution but it didn't work, I'm still getting the same error, should I change something else?

Comment: As you want to include `<myCPPCode/MyCodeDefinitions.h>`, you should write `include_directories(lib)`
Or write `include_directories(lib/myCPPCode)` and include `<MyCodeDefinitions.h>`